# How to prevent Countdowntimer duplicates on new intent

Tags: java, android, runnable, countdowntimer

I have problem with CountDownTimer. I have 2 activity, main and store... in store i have button, if user click button, countdowntimer starts.. if it ends user get +50 coin. It works, but if i go back to mainactivity and after go back to store, the timer duplicates, and user gets double or triple coins.... I fixed it half, but there are little bug in the code....
So if i uncomment startTimer();  in storeactivity from onResume, the countdowntimer duplicates, if i go to mainactivity and go back to store...  if i delete  startTimer();  in storeactivity from onResume, then countdowntimer not updating, if i go to mainactivity and go back to store.... it works, but not updating the countertext automatically...
In the mainactivity timer works well without any problems...
How can i fix this problem?
I tried with make runnable to updateCountDownText();  but it did not worked, maybe i wrote code wrong.
Can somebody help me?
Or how can i make runnable to updateCountDownText();  ?

MainActivity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.util.Locale;

import static com.game.game.variables.coin;
import static com.game.game.variables.life;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String PREFS_NAME_MAIN = "mainpref";

private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 60000;

public static final String PREFS_NAME_TIME = "timepref";

private TextView mTextViewCountDown;


private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

private boolean mTimerRunning;

private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
private long mEndTime;



TextView coinbarText, lifesbarText;
Button playButton, closeButton;
ImageView lifesbarButton, coinbarButton;


private final Context app = this;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    coinbarText = findViewById(R.id.coinbarText);

    lifesbarText = findViewById(R.id.lifesbarText);

    playButton = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    closeButton = findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
    lifesbarButton = findViewById(R.id.lifesbarButton);
    coinbarButton = findViewById(R.id.coinbarButton);

    textupgrade();


    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //finishAffinity();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExitActivity.class));
        }
    });

    mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);


}


private void startTimer() {
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            mTimerRunning = true;
            updateCountDownText();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning = false;

            load();
            coin = coin + 50;
            coinbarText.setText("" + coin);
            resetTimer();
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
            editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
            editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
            editor.apply();
            save();
        }
    }.start();
    mTimerRunning = true;

}

private void resetTimer() {
    mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    updateCountDownText();

}
private void updateCountDownText() {
    int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}


public void store (View store){


    Intent newstore = new Intent(this, StoreActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(newstore);
}



public void exit (View exit){

    Intent newexit = new Intent(this, ExitActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(newexit);
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    load();
    textupgrade();

    coinbarText.setText("" + coin);

}

protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    load();
    //textupgrade();
    textupgrade();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
    updateCountDownText();

    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
            mTimerRunning = false;
            updateCountDownText();

            coin = coin + 50;
            resetTimer();

        } else {
            startTimer();
        }
    }
    coinbarText.setText("" + coin);

}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    load();
    textupgrade();
    coinbarText.setText("" + coin);

}

protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
    editor.apply();

    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    save();
}

private void load()
{
    SharedPreferences varReader = app.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME_MAIN, MODE_PRIVATE);


    coin = varReader.getInt("coin", 100);
    life = varReader.getInt("life", 5);

}

private void save()
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor varReader = app.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME_MAIN, 0).edit();


    varReader.putInt("coin", coin);
    varReader.putInt("life", life);
    varReader.apply();
}

private void textupgrade(){
    coinbarText.setText(""+coin);
    lifesbarText.setText(life + "/5");

}



}
```

StoreActivity:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;

import java.util.Locale;

import static com.game.game.variables.coin;
import static com.game.game.variables.life;


public class StoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RewardedVideoAdListener  {


public static final String PREFS_NAME_MAIN = "mainpref";

private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 60000;

public static final String PREFS_NAME_TIME = "timepref";

private TextView mTextViewCountDown;


private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;

private boolean mTimerRunning;

private long mTimeLeftInMillis;
private long mEndTime;


private final Context app = this;

Button storecloseButton, coin200, coin500, coin1000, adcoinloading, adcoin, timecoin;

TextView coinbarText, lifesbarText;
ImageView lifesbarButton, coinbarButton;
RewardedVideoAd rewardedVideoAd;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);

    storecloseButton = findViewById(R.id.storecloseButton);
    lifesbarButton = findViewById(R.id.lifesbarButton);
    coinbarButton = findViewById(R.id.coinbarButton);
    lifesbarText = findViewById(R.id.lifesbarText);
    coinbarText = findViewById(R.id.coinbarText);
    coin200 = findViewById(R.id.coin200);
    coin500 = findViewById(R.id.coin500);
    coin1000 = findViewById(R.id.coin1000);
    adcoinloading = findViewById(R.id.adcoinloading);
    adcoin = findViewById(R.id.adcoin);
    timecoin = findViewById(R.id.timecoin);


    rewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    rewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

     textupgrade();

    if (rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()){
            adcoin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            adcoinloading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
    else{
      //  adcoinloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       loadAd();
    }


    adcoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()){

                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
                editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
                editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
                editor.apply();
                rewardedVideoAd.show();
            }
        }
    });

    mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);

    timecoin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mTimerRunning) {
                //pauseTimer();
            } else {
                startTimer();

            }
        }
    });

}

private void startTimer() {
    mEndTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + mTimeLeftInMillis;
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            mTimerRunning = true;
            updateCountDownText();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            load();
            mTimerRunning = false;
            updateButtons();
            coin = coin + 50;
            coinbarText.setText("" + coin);
            resetTimer();
            save();
        }
    }.start();
    mTimerRunning = true;
    updateButtons();
}
private void pauseTimer() {
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    mTimerRunning = false;
    updateButtons();
}
private void resetTimer() {
    mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    updateCountDownText();
    updateButtons();
}
private void updateCountDownText() {
    int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;
    String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
    mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
}
private void updateButtons() {
    if (mTimerRunning) {
        //mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        timecoin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        //mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 1000) {
            timecoin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        } else {
            timecoin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < START_TIME_IN_MILLIS) {
            //mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            //mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}


public void storeback (View storeback){


    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
    editor.apply();
    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    save();


    finish();
}


private void loadAd() {
    if (!rewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()){
        rewardedVideoAd = null;
        rewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        rewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
        rewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}




@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    adcoin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    adcoinloading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
    editor.apply();

}


@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    loadAd();
    adcoin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    adcoinloading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
    updateCountDownText();
    updateButtons();
    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
            mTimerRunning = false;
            updateCountDownText();
            updateButtons();
            //coin = coin + 50;
            resetTimer();
            timecoin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            //startTimer();
            updateCountDownText();
        }
    }



}


@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
    load();
    coin = coin + 50;
    save();
    textupgrade();

}


@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

}


@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

}


@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    rewardedVideoAd.pause(this);
    save();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadAd();
    load();
    textupgrade();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    mTimeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong("millisLeft", START_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
    mTimerRunning = prefs.getBoolean("timerRunning", false);
    updateCountDownText();
    updateButtons();
    if (mTimerRunning) {
        mEndTime = prefs.getLong("endTime", 0);
        mTimeLeftInMillis = mEndTime - System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis < 0) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = 0;
            mTimerRunning = false;
            updateCountDownText();
            updateButtons();
            coin = coin + 50;
            resetTimer();
            timecoin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            //startTimer();
            updateCountDownText();


        }
    }
    coinbarText.setText("" + coin);

}




@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    loadAd();
    load();
    textupgrade();
    coinbarText.setText("" + coin);

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    //rewardedVideoAd.destroy(this);
    super.onDestroy();

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    loadAd();
    load();
    textupgrade();

    coinbarText.setText("" + coin);

}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putLong("millisLeft", mTimeLeftInMillis);
    editor.putBoolean("timerRunning", mTimerRunning);
    editor.putLong("endTime", mEndTime);
    editor.apply();
    if (mCountDownTimer != null) {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    }
    save();

}


private void load()
{
    SharedPreferences varReader = app.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME_MAIN, MODE_PRIVATE);

    coin = varReader.getInt("coin", 100);
    life = varReader.getInt("life", 5);
}

private void save()
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor varReader = app.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME_MAIN, 0).edit();

    varReader.putInt("coin", coin);
    varReader.putInt("life", life);
    varReader.apply();
}

private void textupgrade(){
    coinbarText.setText(""+ coin);
    lifesbarText.setText(life + "/5");

}

}
```

Comment: use onPause() to stop timer

Comment: Thanks, i cancelled timer on onPause() and cancelled when start new intent. It works now.